# One to Many relationship between Custom Model and AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to create a one to many relationship between a custom table (called `Organization`) and `AspNetUsers`

- Each User can only belong to one Organization
- Each Organization can have many Users

**I would like the `Organization` table to have a column containing each User belonging to that organization.**

The reason I need this --> for any `Organization` I need to be able to retrieve all the Users from that Organization.

The **`Organization`** model has a property - ICollection of ApplicationUser:

```
public class Organization
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

In the **ApplicationUser** model:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    }
```

At this stage when I add a migration and update database:

- I get a column for Organization in `AspNetUsers` table: `Organization_Id`
- But I do not get a column for list of Users in the `Organization` table

This is my `AppDbContext`:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
 
        }
        public DbSet<Orgnization> Organization{ get; set; }
 
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
 
            builder.Entity<Organization>(b =>
            {
                b.HasKey(p => p.Id);
 
                b.HasMany(p => p.ApplicationUsers)
                .WithOne(p => p.Organization);
            });
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: _"But I do not get a column for list of Users in the Organization table"_ - this is expected. How could a list of users be stored in a column in a relational database? One-to-many relationships alaways work this way and you don't need anything like that. Given your configuration, `Organization.ApplicationUsers` will be the collection of all users belonging to that organization whenever you query it using EF. Ex: `from org in ctx.Organizations where org.ApplicationUsers.Any() select org`

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a column for Organization in AspNetUsers table: Organization_Id
> But I do not get a column for list of Users in the Organization table

This is the default convention when create One-to-Many relationships in EF core, after configure the relationships between then, we could find the related entities via the navigation property.

More detail information, check the following tutorials:

[One-to-Many Relationship Conventions in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx)

[Configuring One To Many Relationships in Entity Framework Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration)

> for any Organization I need to be able to retrieve all the Users from
> that Organization.

To load the related entities, you could use the `Include` method, check the linq statement in the action method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context; 
    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    { 
        _context = context;
    }
     

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //Based on user's name to get the organization.
            var organization = _context.Organization.Include(c=>c.ApplicationUsers).Where(c => c.ApplicationUsers.Any(d => d.UserName == User.Identity.Name)).ToList();
              
            //require using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
            //based on the organization name, find all users belong to the specific organization.
            var result = _context.Organization.Include(c => c.ApplicationUsers).Where(c => c.Name == "microsoft")
                .SelectMany(c => c.ApplicationUsers.Select(d => new { UserName = d.UserName, OrganizationName = c.Name })).ToList();

        }
        return View();
    }
```

The debug screenshot as below:

[image]

More detail information, check [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) and [Tutorial: Read related data - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Appreciated!